# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 30339: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, azure, encoding

Here is the problematic code

Initiate session handler

```
session = requests.Session()
```

Programmatically gets the SAML assertion, opens the initial IdP url and follows all of the HTTP302 redirects, and gets the resulting login page

```
formresponse = session.get(idpentryurl, verify=sslverification)
```

Capture the `idpauthformsubmiturl`, which is the final url after all the 302s

```
idpauthformsubmiturl = formresponse.url
```

Parse the response and extract all the necessary values in order to build a dictionary of all of the form values the IdP expects

```
formsoup = BeautifulSoup(formresponse.text.decode('utf8'))
payload = {}
```

Debug output:

```
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): myapps.microsoft.com
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https: //myapps.microsoft.com:443 "GET /signin/AWS%20CMD%20(Audit)/18216d2a-eef8-4fde-962c-50cf615f3f5b HTTP/1.1" 302 244
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com:443 "GET /applications/signin/AWS%20CMD%20(Audit)/18216d2a-eef8-4fde-962c-50cf615f3f5b HTTP/1.1" 302 94
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): login.microsoftonline.com
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://login.microsoftonline.com:443 "GET /common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=0000000c-0000-0000-c000-000000000000&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Faccount.activedirectory.windowsazure.com%2F&response_mode=form_post&response_type=code%20id_token&scope=openid%20profile&state=OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties%3DmIDzRLZskQlxxtgB9rjxiHrNVmQJpcUVaK8wuZ3A2PMIyBE8fzxkXDcroNhC4wyof9OK9OlhqH0J_stoYSEIhKiEzx4O3XDW4rS4xyFTitGmztuV3ozOJhX5uafmQm_XmKnXEjEt9CNwFbp2Kju3rRGLAXRViD3byQ7XpwdXkeXoDFLwmy5OIXQgzvPjSsc7Jx7xEXMHckDwElhBOBFXmJVYCkHYx6cB-3yjwGJHX6RQ2lfx6CUg7x2PqPkbo4WsUxbZDAJZsMqYXyVRZGSDqAgU3gSezlHNgZGh-nblkxj7Dw6rdMVKmpNWZWkjp3zI3OjWa91FTrVc0mC9gIQC-BC4zaF-FrwQ4rHPbQlisQoS6-S1qM8ca_cEi6CfFaHh2lrtB-xdNEVum97Mzmlg9g&nonce=1507770263.sCv6L2a21eQuLNKaXL3zog&nux=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 15838
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "formauth.py", line 62, in <module>

formsoup = BeautifulSoup(formresponse.text.decode('utf8'))

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)

**UnicodeEncodeError:** 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 30342: ordinal not in range(128)
```

trying tricks like the following did not help: in response body replace non-utf8 chars with space

```
formresponse.encoding = formresponse.apparent_encoding
formsoupba = bytearray(formresponse.text, 'utf8')
for i, val in enumerate(formsoupba):
    if val > 128:
        formsoupba[i] = 32
        formsoup = BeautifulSoup(formsoupba.decode('utf8'), "html.parser")
```

will yield the following error:

return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 30334: invalid start byte

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to decode a unicode character (`\u2019`, a quotation mark) into `utf-8`, which should work fine.
Something is then trying to encode that back to ascii - some bs4 parser perhaps?

It doesn't matter - here's the shotgun approach if you're willing to lose the odd `’` character:

```
clean_text = formresponse.text.encode('utf8').decode('ascii', 'ignore')
formsoup = BeautifulSoup(clean_text, "html.parser")
```

This simply `ignore`s any encoding errors, meaning you lose the character. check out the docs here for some other options beyond ignore: https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html

A more in depth approach would be to find the actual encoding of the page - https://login.microsoftonline.com:443 claims to be `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`, but clearly it is not if it contains those kinds of chars. I think this might be throwing off BeautifulSoup. Try giving bs4 a few different encodings, such as `cp1252` and `latin-1`.

Comment: your shotgun workaround did fix the error message, so thanks heaps for that. On the other hand, I am getting a new error that might or might not be related to the now dropped character :) I guess I just have to figure out why I am getting a "Response did not contain a valid SAML assertion". Any way, thanks for the fix